# Force https and www on AWS load balancer

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm using an AWS load balancer and currently redirecting all http to https with this .htaccess regex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This works fine because I have health checks that must be accessed on 80. However, currently when trying to access https www I get a DNS error.

What would regex look like that routes everything to https://www and passes a health check on http on my instances?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the DNS error that you get? Is it possible you have no DNS entry for the www subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

At AWS behind the load balancer, you have to handle things differently. You won't be checking for https in the normal way because of the SSL Offloading with your Load Balancer. You would need to check the X-Forwarded-Proto

It should be as following.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`
```

Comment: Excellent solution, worked perfectly, spent hours scratching my head why my typical htaccess works on local and stagin but not on live as my live consists of aws load balancer. Thanks